# API design guideline for Vue.js integration

Tags: rest, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am a backend developer and the frontend will be using Vue.js (not exist yet).

I am curious if standard restful API design already work nicely, or do I need special consideration when I am designing the API?

Comment: In general use rest or graphql.  Would be a better question for forum.vuejs.org than stackoverflow, you will get much more detailed discussion.

Comment: Since you will be writing your own API layer between your store and your backend, you can go with what ever is convenient for you. Vue (and Vuex) are very flexible in this regard.